# unexpected formatting when dumping to json

Tags: python, json

I have a python program that collects data from few sensors. I receive the data as string, like so  `{ "hum": 48.61, "ts": 1421409826365, "temp": 27.43 }` I want to save this into a .json file. So I did the following

- Took the string and converted it into a dict
- I used json.loads(string) to achieve this.
- Then I added the dictionaries into a list
- Then wrote the list into a file, using json.dump

The expected result was a json file with the following.

```
[
    {
        "light": 666, 
        "ts": 1421409825703, 
        "clr": {
            "r": 0, 
            "b": 0, 
            "g": 0
        }, 
        "prox": 62
    },

    {
        "hum": 48.61, 
        "ts": 1421409826365, 
        "temp": 27.43
    }
]
```

A list containing the sensor Data, separated by  `,`

What I got was the following.

```
[
    {
        "light": 666, 
        "ts": 1421409825703, 
        "clr": {
            "r": 0, 
            "b": 0, 
            "g": 0
        }, 
        "prox": 62
    }
][
    {
        "hum": 48.61, 
        "ts": 1421409826365, 
        "temp": 27.43
    }
]
```

Each of the sensor data are added to individual list and they are not separated by commas.

How do I ensure they are all written to  **One** list and are seperated by commas?.

Here is my code.

```
def write_to_file(string):
    jdata = json.loads(string)
    jlist =[]
    jlist.append(jdata)
    with open("Data.json", "a") as outfile:
        json.dump(jlist,outfile, indent=4)
```

Comment: ......or you could just replace `][` with `,` in the file when you load it :p (yeah I agree, it's a horrible solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `write_to_file` from a different function. Each time you are clearing `jlist` and you are writing to that file each time only a single json-construct.

To solve this, you could do:

```
jlist = []  # make jlist a globally accessible variable

def write_to_file(string):
    jdata = json.loads(string)
    jlist.append(jdata)
    with open("Data.json", "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(jlist,outfile, indent=4)
```

In your version, you are *appending* each time to the end of the file. That's why the call to `json.dump` will continue from the last json object written, which is a single-item list (that item being a dictionary).

An alternative solution that does not use globals (thanks for pointing that out @bruno), that does not re-read the file each time (IO-access is slow) would be to return the `jlist` to the calling function too:

```
def write_to_file(string, jlist):
    jdata = json.loads(string)
    jlist.append(jdata)
    with open("Data.json", "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(jlist,outfile, indent=4)
    return jlist
```

Just make sure to capture `jlist` from the calling function and to pass it back in.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, I said the OP *could* use it. I wouldn't do it like that either.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you get only one json string at a time and cannot build jlist in one loop, you'll need to store it for writing after you've gathered all the data. For example:

```
class Jlist:
    def __init__(self):
        self._jlist = []

    def add(self, json_string):
        self._jlist.append(json.loads(json_string))

    def write(self, file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(self._jlist, outfile, indent=4)
```

In this case, you need the class in order to retain `_jlist` between calls to add.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it took me a couple minutes to figure it out, but that's really obvious...  For each sensor input, you're opening "Data.json" in append mode and dump a json list to it, so the result is just what you asked for.

The solution here is to reload the existing data in "Data.json", append to that list, and write it back erasing the previous version, ie:

```
def write_to_file(string):
    jdata = json.loads(string)
    # XXX you may want to handle the case where the file
    # does not yet exist
    with open("Data.json") as infile:
        jlist = json.load(infile)
    jlist.append(jdata)
    with open("Data.json", "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(jlist,outfile, indent=4)
```

Just take care that this code won't work concurrently on a same file...

Comment: That's a fine workaround except it has O(n^3) insertion time complexity.

Comment: The `Data.json` is created during run time. so when using `json.load` I'm getting a `No JSON object could be decoded` error.

Comment: @cyberbemon: please read the comment in the code: "XXX you may want to handle the case where the file does not yet exist" (or "is empty", of course).

Comment: @msw : first make it work, then make it right, then make it fast - if necessary ;) (which doesn't mean your comment is irrelevant - it's obviously not the optimal solution).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the right answer is that making the list and saving it to file should be done by two separate functions (in fact msw's solution, using a class, really looks like the best option to me).

Anyways, if you still want one function to do both things, this (admittedly dirty) solution might work:

```
def write_to_file(string, clear = False, _jlist = []):
    if clear:
        _jlist[:] = []
    jdata = json.loads(string)
    _jlist.append(jdata)
    with open("Data.json", "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(_jlist, outfile, indent=4)
```

Here `_jlist` isn't global, it is contained within the  scope of the function, but it is **only** cleared when you call it with `clear=True` as argument. So remember to do this, to clear the list when you need a fresh json.
I wrote `_jlist` with an underscore because you shouldn't really use it as argument. It's declared as parameter because this way the list object is created only once, and not every time the function is called.